# Where is Note Pad Gadget in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

Where is my Note Pad Gadget in Windows 7? Where to download it from (One which was in Vista by default was best one for me)

Answer (score 6):

It no longer exists.

Why? It's migrated to it's own standalone app, included in the OS, [Sticky Notes](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/products/features/sticky-notes). It's better, give it a shot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like it is still avaliable for [download over at Windows 7 Themes](http://windows7themes.net/windows-7-notepad-gadget.html)

[image]